# Reduce If statement by looping and Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying to shorten a couple of if-statement

Previously I had following:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?()]/);
var ltr = /[a-zA-Z ]+/;
var mistakeA;
var mistakeB;
var mistakeC;

var input = document.myform.myinputname.value;
var input2 = document.myform.myinputname.value;

   if(ltr.test(input) && !(regex.test(input))){

      myinputid.style.border ='1.5px solid red;
      mistakeA;
   } 
     else if  (regex.test(input) && !(ltr.test(input))){

       myinputid.style.border ='1.5px solid red;
        mistakeB;
    }  // same for input 2
```

So basically it's a check if the input is correct.
And everything worked so far logicalwise. But i had too many If-Statement so now i tried to shorten them as following:

```
  var input [input1,input2,input3,input4];

  for (i= 0; i < input.length; i++){
      if (ltr.test(input[]) &&!(regex.test(input[]))){
         myinputid.style.border='1.5px solid red';
      } else { alert("noarray");
  }
}
```

So what am i doing wrong? Or how can i shorten my If-Statements? I have 8 Statements with the same structure.
The array (which are the inputs ) aren't called. it's not working because the .test(input[]) must be somehow wrong.

Comment: you didn't tell, what your problem exactly is with the new one.

Comment: What are `mistakeA`, `mistakeB` ...?

Comment: can't you use a **xor** to shorten your if statements? or adleast make it more efficient?

Comment: the array (which are the inputs ) aren't called. it's not working because the .test(input[]) must be somehow wrong.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir these are just outputs ( not relevant )

Comment: @Jdoe2016 you forgot the subscript. It's should be `if (ltr.test(input[  i  ]) && !(regex.test(input[  i  ]))){` (notice the `i` in `input[i]`)!

Comment: @Syntac yeah **xor** would be possible but the if statement would be still too wrong, right? but that's a first step to what i'm looking for,thx

Comment: And the array declaration is wrong as well! It sould be `var input  =  [....];`.

Comment: i didn't copy my original. i tried to make it simpler. but i didn't refer input[i] but even with this it doesn't work. any idea?

Comment: it works now i think, let me testand tell you afterwards.

Comment: Do you want your inputs to only contain letters (a to z, case-insensitive) and spaces ?

Comment: Please don't deface your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var input = []; // that's how you declare an array

input.push(document.myform.myinputname.value); // add a new item
input.push(document.myform.myinputname.value); // add another
// ...

// Or: (notice =)
//var input =  [document.myform.myinputname.value, document.myform.myinputname.value, ...];

// just an advice (use var i instead of i) to not make i global
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if (ltr.test(input[i]) && !(regex.test(input[i]))){ // use subscripts to indicate which item of the array to test
        myinputid.style.border='1.5px solid red';
    } else { alert("noarray"); }
}
```